# Kotlin object literal implementing wild-carded, self-referencing generic interface

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an interface (in Java) that takes a self-referencing generic argument, and I would like to create an object literal in Kotlin that implements it. In Java, I do this by not including the generic types (unsafe), but I cannot figure out how to do it in Kotlin.

Here is an example in just Kotlin, though in my case the interface is in Java.

```
interface Generic<V, T : Generic<V, T>> {
    fun stuff(x: V)
}

class Test {
    // In Java I would write new Generic() { ... }
    val v = object : Generic<*, *> {
        override fun stuff(x: Object) {
            doSomethingThatDoesntCareAboutTypes()
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
val v = object<T : Generic<*, T>> : T {
    override fun stuff(x: Object) {
        doSomethingThatDoesntCareAboutTypes()
    }
}
```

How can I do something similar to this without having to change the interface, which is in a different module and can't easily be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Star projections are particularly useful when **consuming** generic interfaces and rarely when defining the implementations. (Similarly to Java's `?`).

To be able to define an `object` that implements `Generic` you need to provide type arguments that satisfy the constraints. [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) in particular is the subtype of all Kotlin types so you can write:

```
val v = object : Generic<Any, Nothing> {
    override fun stuff(x: Any) {
        doSomethingThatDoesntCareAboutTypes()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. In fact, once putting in Nothing, IntelliJ helped me convert it to the more succinct lambda version: `Generic<Any, Nothing> { ... }`

Comment: Er, just ran into a problem with this. I have another method that accepts something along the lines if `Generic<T, ? super Generic<T>>` which the Nothing doesn't work with...

Comment: So, I solved that with an explicit cast, which is reasonable enough, since I'm eschewing type safety intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

According to the documentation, the star-projection on an invariant type such as V in your example resolves to . If the T parameter wasn't self-referencing you could use:

```
object : Generic<Any, Any> {}
```

Since T is self referencing you'll need to actually define a named class for T to reference.

```
class Test {
    val v2 : Generic<*, *>

    init {
        class Impl: Generic<Any, Impl> {
            override fun stuff(x: Any) {
                // ...
            }
        }

        v2 = Impl()
    }
}
```

Another posibility would be to create an interface that resolves the self-referencing generic for you.

```
interface SelfRef<V> : Generic<V, SelfRef<V>>

class Test2 {
    val v = object: SelfRef<Any> {
        override fun stuff(x: Any) {

        }
    }
}
```